# Xamarin iOS FirebaseAuth.Instance is always null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-authentication

Im using Firebase.iOS.Core v6.6.6 and Firebase.iOS.Auth v6.5.1 with this code snippet

```
 public async Task LoginWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
 {
      var auth = Auth.DefaultInstance;
      var result = await auth.SignInWithPasswordAsync(email, password);
 }
```

auth is always `null` and throw `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

Comment: See following : https://www.lindseybroos.be/2020/03/xamarin-forms-and-firebase-authentication/

Comment: @jdweng It's not work for me :(

Comment: Where are you getting the null?

Comment: @lilyang did you get it to work? I am stuck on the same issue, and after trying a lot, still not able to fix it :(

Comment: can you please tell us if you got it to work, i'm now on my 3rd day of fulltime trying to fix this, i probably lost 5kg of weight cause of frustration, and i tried literally everything and i can't manage to get it working ..

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth v 8.10.0.

Downgrading all Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.x packages to 6.9.x solved it automagically.

No clue why, but there you have it.